# bundle install failed because of openssl

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl

when I run `bundle install` , I get message bellow on console .

it seems  all these message are  related to openssl

how can I fix this error?

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::BN::CONSTTIME
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::BN::CONSTTIME
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::BN::CONSTTIME
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:322:in `clear_paths': undefined method `reset' for Gem::Security:Module (NoMethodError)

    Gem::Security.reset if defined?(Gem::Security)
                 ^^^^^^
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:174:in `clear_paths'
     ...
```

i searched the internet about this but got little about this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @anothermh mentioned ,do not use brew to install ruby ,use rvm instead

1. install rvm
2. `brew uninstall ruby`
3. install ruby and  specify openssl path

```
rvm install 3.2.0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's just a mismatch on your version of rubygems and your version of Ruby that you can resolve by updating rubygems:

```bash
gem update --system
```

I say *possible* but I don't expect that will work. Generally, esoteric problems like this are best resolved by purging and starting again from scratch. That would mean:

1. Uninstall Ruby (`brew uninstall ruby`)
2. Uninstall OpenSSL (`brew uninstall openssl`)
3. Reinstall both
4. Try `bundle install` again

But it's also possible *that* won't work either because it's the same tooling that got you into this situation. What I'd recommend instead is that you use a version manager for Ruby. Tools like [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) and [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and [rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm) will download and compile Ruby from scratch, and if they need a specific version of OpenSSL to do so then they'll download that during the compilation process so that you don't have to.

Version managers are preferred over brew because they only update when you tell them to. If you install Ruby with a manager and it works then it will continue to work; if you install with brew then brew will update and upgrade Ruby as it sees fit, even when you're not intending to update it.

Switching to a version manager will have some initial overhead in terms of effort but it's likely to save you a lot of time and headaches over the long term.

Comment: `because it is required by ldid, which is currently installed.`